# Laravel strange "trying to get property of non object" error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to extend an app called eBot, which was originally made with Symfony 1.4. I am using Laravel 5.1.

What I am trying to do is return an array of "Teams" along with their season in the following format:

```
{TeamName}<small>{SeasonName}</small>
```

Here is my current code:

```
$teams = [];

foreach(eBotTeam::all() as $team)
{
     $teamSeasonPivot = eBotTeamSeasonPivot::where('team_id', '=', $team->id)->get()->first();
     $season = $teamSeasonPivot->season;

     $teams[$team->id] = $team->name . '<small>' . $season->name . '</small>';
}
```

My models look like the following:

```
class eBotSeason extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'seasons';

    protected $connection = 'ebot';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'event', 'start', 'end', 'link', 'logo', 'active'];

    public function matches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\Doesplay\Models\eBotMatch', 'season_id');
    }
}

class eBotTeam extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teams';

    protected $connection = 'ebot';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'shorthandle', 'flag', 'link', 'dp_team_id'];
}

class eBotTeamSeasonPivot extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teams_in_seasons';

    protected $connection = 'ebot';

    protected $fillable = ['season_id', 'team_id'];

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Doesplay\Models\eBotTeam');
    }

    public function season()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Doesplay\Models\eBotSeason');
    }
}
```

When I die and dump `$teamSeasonPivot` or `$season` it works fine and displays a model as it should. However, if I try to put it into the array as shown above it returns a `Trying to get property of non-object` error on `$season = $teamSeasonPivot->season;`.

In the error dump it shows the array (`$teams`) as it should.

If anyone has any ideas why this happens please let me know.

**Edit:** Here is the actual error:
Line 20 is `$season = $teamSeasonPivot->season;`
[image]

Comment: Show us the _failing_ code, not the working code. Also, show us the complete error message, it contains more information about the non-object (for example; if it's an array or a null value). Could it be that your $teamSeasonPivot is an array (which is a non-object)?